# ThreeJs: Glitch appears when the texture is moved

Tags: three.js

would anyone be able to help me solve this problem that is driving me crazy?
I am mapping an equirectangular texture on a cube and when I move the coordinates on the x axis this glitch appears as in the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEWrz.jpg).

I also give you the link where you can see the code:
https://codepen.io/andrea-torza/pen/oNobKyP

Moving the "center.x" control with a value other than 0 causes the glitch to appear.

I think the problem is in this piece of code:

```
if((tmp_x==0) && (tmp_z<0)) {
  var p = Math.floor(i / 3);
  if ((positions[p * 3 * 3] < 0) || (positions[(p + 1) * 3 * 3] < 0) || (positions[(p + 2) * 3 * 3] < 0)) {
    theta = -Math.PI;
  }
}
```

I thank you in advance!

Comment: Equirectangular projection is for spheres, not cubes. Convert your equirectangular projection to a cube map with this tool: https://jaxry.github.io/panorama-to-cubemap/

Comment: I need the equirectangular texture to be projected into a cube and I can't convert textures with an external tool.